# @radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu content is displayed incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, menu, dropdown

I am using @radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu with my Button component inside the Trigger (with `asChild` prop) and the dropdown content is displayed incorrectly (if I replace Button with the html button, the content is displayed normally).

For some reason the dropdown content css is like this `transform: translate3d(0px, -200%, 0px)` when I am using my Button component, but when I used the html button everything works fine

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as DropdownMenu from "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu";

const Button = (props) => {
  return <button {...props} />;
};

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <DropdownMenu.Root>
          <DropdownMenu.Trigger asChild>
            <Button type="button">test 1</Button>
            {/* <button type="button">test 2</button> */}
          </DropdownMenu.Trigger>

          <DropdownMenu.Content>
            <DropdownMenu.Item>menu item</DropdownMenu.Item>
            <DropdownMenu.Item>menu item</DropdownMenu.Item>
            <DropdownMenu.Item>menu item</DropdownMenu.Item>
          </DropdownMenu.Content>
        </DropdownMenu.Root>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Use forwardRef for your custom button/trigger and it should work as expected.

Comment: @AndyCoupe You should add this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

**@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu incorrect position**

also spent a lot of time around this 'forwardRef' but it will not work in case if you have a  component as in this example, it will work only if you use  tag

here is an example with forwardRef - https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-fast-rifc6?file=/App.js:3996-4176

So, the solution is easy than I expected
just wrap the component into 'DIV'

```
<DropdownMenu.Trigger asChild>
  <div>
    <Button type="button">test 1</Button>
  </div>       
</DropdownMenu.Trigger>
```